# Empty Cart Expiration Time For WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to empty the cart after 25 min added to the cart, in Woocommerce?

what the code or hook can do this on Woocommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the plugin https://github.com/liquidweb/woo-cart-expiration
or even you can set in WooCommerce->settings->Products then click on inventory and in Hold stock (minutes) set minutes